# How to make conection line between elements desktop and mobile virsion?

Tags: html, css, sass, less, css-transitions

Need help to make a stratetgy to implement this as a DESKTOP version:

[image]

And then biggest problem switch the desktop into Mobile version and to work and looks like this:

[image]

Any opinion article idea is welcome :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That design can be achieved with a little nested flexbox acrobatic.

Below a quick, rough and dirty example just to demonstrate the mechanic. Please feel free to adapt code to your needs.

**NOTES:**

- The line behind the number actual is ONE line (`div class=unit__timeline`) just to demonstrate. To make it nice you need two 'div-lines' on live server. You are able to align them by same technique ... you just have to calulate them to the needed sizes/height/width of your section by same mechanic (absolute positioning and sizing by calulation values for top/right/bottom/left).
- Same to breakpoints: there are just two (mobile and up from small desktops). Please calculate sizes for font-size, wanted grid, etc. to your needs.

```css
html {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.unit__wrapper {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.unit {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.unit__number {
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}
.unit__number span {
  display: block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  font-size: 20px;
  background: steelblue;
  border: 15px solid white;
  border-radius: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.unit__content {
  flex-grow: 1;
  padding: 0 15px;
  text-align: center;
}

.unit__timeline {
  position: absolute;
  top: 32.5px;
  left: calc( 100% / 6 );
  right: calc( 100% / 6 );
  height: 10px;
  background: green;
  z-index: -1;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .unit__wrapper {
    flex-direction: column;
  }

  .unit {
    flex-direction: row;
  }

  .unit__number {
    padding: 20px 0;
  }

  .unit__content {
    text-align: left;
    padding: 0;
  }

  .unit__timeline {
    left: 32.5px;
    top: 60px;
    bottom: 60px;
    right: auto;
    height: auto;
    width: 10px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="unit__wrapper">

    <div class="unit__timeline"></div>

    <div class="unit">
        <div class="unit__number"><span>1</span></div>
        <div class="unit__content">
            Li Europan lingues es membres del sam familie.
            Lor separat existentie es un myth. Por scientie, 
            musica, sport etc, litot Europa usa li sam vocabular.
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="unit">
        <div class="unit__number"><span>2</span></div>
        <div class="unit__content">
            Li Europan lingues es membres del sam familie.
            Lor separat existentie es un myth. Por scientie, 
            musica, sport etc, litot Europa usa li sam vocabular.
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="unit">
        <div class="unit__number"><span>3</span></div>
        <div class="unit__content">
            Li Europan lingues es membres del sam familie.
            Lor separat existentie es un myth. Por scientie, 
            musica, sport etc, litot Europa usa li sam vocabular.
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```